# Does Fabric allow us to see a list of events for a specific user, leading up to a certain event at a certain time point?

Tags: ios, google-fabric

Assuming that we use Fabric SDK for iOS from http://www.fabric.io, and that we have an iOS app with authentication and custom events set up for most of the steps the user takes, is it possible to see a list of events for a specific user leading upto a specific event or crash at a certain time point?

For example.

User John Doe got a crash issue which was reported in Crashlytics, while he was trying to change his profile picture within the app.

Are we able to obtain a list of events like this for John Doe:

- Auto login 11:22:23
- Show user profile screen 11:22:50
- Edit user profile 11:23:12
- Change photo 11:23:31
- Upload from Photos 11:23:40
- 'app crashed' 11:23:41

Answer (score 2):

Todd from Fabric here - This is definitely possible. We have the ability to create key:value stores in logs within crash reports.

You'll use something like:

```
- (void)setObjectValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key;
```

Set it when it happens in your app and it will be included on the session detail page for the crash.

Check out this page: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html

Comment: Thanks. This seems to cover most of my question. It's only possible to see this "journey" when a crash happens, correct? I cannot open the logs otherwise to see how a user behaves within the app. 

The reason I am asking this is because I had a scenario in which the user contacted for support because he/she had issues with a part of the app that's hard to debug (but didn't have a crash), so I wanted to see if I could see what the user did to produce that issue by following a list of Events.

I guess I was looking at it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Read their official docs: [Fabric Answers Events](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/answers/answers-events.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, could you point me to the page where I can see the event list like above for one specific user? What does that page look like.

Comment: Have you integrated fabric?-- and the void you e.g. Change the user profile, add an answer event, once the user changes their profile, an event with details will be send to you

Comment: I have integrated everything, and I can see the cumulative data in dashboard. Please read my question in detail.